# Repository of SKOS Vocabularies

Tags: semantic-web, vocabulary

Is there any repository or list of freely available SKOS (or even not SKOS) vocabs?
I need some special vocabs and want to know if they are already exist or not.
I found some well-known ones like http://www.eionet.europa.eu/GEMET or agrovoc (which is included in [KEA](http://www.nzdl.org/Kea/download.html)), but these don't  fit my needs.

Thanks,
HM

Comment: possible duplicate of [SKOS Vocabulary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841955/skos-vocabulary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no actual repository of SKOS thesauri as far as I know, but here are two more links:

http://vocabulary.semantic-web.at/PoolParty/wiki/semweb

http://data.reegle.info/thesaurus/guide

Answer (score 1):

I normally start looking for vocabs in two places -- Swoogle and the linked data cloud.

1. Swoogle: http://swoogle.umbc.edu/
2. Linked Data: http://linkeddata.org/

For linked data, click the diagram - look at the relevant areas, and see what the major linked data repositories are using in terms of their vocab/ontology.

Looks like there are some folks looking specifically at SKOS vocabularies:

http://poolparty.punkt.at/